# Access consecutive entries of array in C

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

Let's say I have this:

```
uint8_t a[8] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08};
```

If I:

```
printf("%lu", ((uint64_t*) a)[0]);
```

I'll get:

```
0x0102030405060708
```

How can I do this with a non-standard size? ex. `((uint94_t) a)[0]`.
Of course, there is no `uint94_t` and that's what I'm asking. How to read a non-standard number of bits (or even bytes, it does the job for me as well)?

Note: I don't care for printf's specific string (so it can parse non-standard amount of bit/bytes) but in the datatype

Answer (score 2):

`"%ul"` means `"%u"` (unsigned int) followed by the letter `"l"`.  Maybe you intended `"%lu"` (unsigned long) however both of those are incorrect for `uint64_t`.

The proper specifier is found in `inttypes.h`, and it is `"%" PRIu64`.

Also this doesn't print `0x` as you suggested , it prints a decimal representation. Use `"%" PRIx64` for hex representation (which also doesn't print the leading `0x`).

---

Moving on, your code causes [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/1505939).  According to the strict aliasing rule, it is not allowed to use an expression of type `uint64_t` to access any variable that was not written as `uint64_t` or `int64_t` in the first place.

You can avoid the strict aliasing rule by using a variable of the correct type, either in a union or otherwise, e.g.:

```
uint64_t x;
memcpy(&x, a, sizeof x);
printf("%" PRIu64 "\n", x);
```

Your compiler will optimize this so don't worry about it being inefficient or something.

Note that the output of this is *implementation-defined* as the compiler could choose various ways of ordering the bits of a `uint64_t` . Two common orders are *big-endian* and *little-endian*.

---

The other part of your question is about other integer types. Unfortunately you're stuck with what your compiler provided.  Most likely it didn't offer `uint94_t`.  You'll have to roll your own code to achieve what you want. For example you could simulate 96-bit big endian:

```
uint8_t a[12] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C};

uint64_t x = 0, y = 0;
mempcy((unsigned char *)&x + 4, a, 4); 
memcpy(&y, a+4, 8);
printf("%" PRIx64 "%" PRIx64 "\n", x, y);
```

Of course you could just print it character by character.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of googling got me the answer...
The answer is bitfields!

```
typedef union {
    __uint128_t i : 96;
} __attribute__((packed)) uint96_t;
printf("%ul", ((uint96_t*) a)[0]);
```

Comment: note: This causes undefined behaviour, also it's unlikely to produce 96 bits worth of output, try making `a` have 12 bytes as in my last example